# How to fix python request pagination that is not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to paginate with python request but I can't seem to get the total page and also the JSON response does not update with the change of page.

```py
url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/1003-York-pa/search?query=ice%20cream'
api_url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/electrode/api/search'

    params = {
        'query': word,
        'cat_id': 0,
        'ps': 24,
        'offset': 0,
        'prg': 'desktop',
        'stores': re.search(r'store/(\d+)', url).group(1)
    }

    data1 = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    

    num_pages = data1['pagination']['pages'][-1]['page']

    for page in range(0, num_pages + 1):
 
            params = {
                'query': word,
                'cat_id': 0,
                'page':page,     // try to update the new page
                'ps': 24,
                'offset': 0,
                'prg': 'desktop',
                'stores': re.search(r'store/(\d+)', url).group(1)
            }

     data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your indentation of the last line is wrong, it needs to be nested inside the `for` loop.  This way it goes through the loop and only after that it does a single request for the latest page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second `params` settings (inside for loop) you need to remove `'offset': 0,`, because it instructs server to fetch from very first result of first page every time. This is the only main bug. After this fix I started getting different products for each page request.

Secondly for loop should probably start from `1`, as pages are numerated from 1 as I see by response.

Thirdly probably second `requests.get` call should be inside pagination for loop, or you just copy pasted code with wrong indentation.